# Is it possible to send and read directly with the file descriptor from both sockets and files, like one can in c?

Tags: python, sockets

The file descriptor value from a socket can be gotten with socket.fileno(). However, you can't write to that integer.

Same thing with files opened with open().

With c and c++, the file descriptor is just an integer that can be used with read and write.

It there anyway around this?

edit:
When I do:

```
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("google.com", 80))
os.write(s.fileno(), "foo")
os.read(s.fileno(), 100)
```

It just hangs forever.
Edit2:
I got it working.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?  You can already read and write to the objects using their ordinary methods.

Comment: Well, you can use the C stdlib functions using `ctypes`.

Comment: Try sending an actual HTTP request, e.g. `GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n`

Comment: Re: your last edit.... how did you get it to work?

Comment: By connecting to a netcat listener.
I assume that if I sent a legitimate http request, I would've gotten a response.

Answer (score 1):

You can read/write with file descriptors using [`os.read()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.read) and [`os.write()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.write).

Comment: ...except on Windows where the socket isn't recognized by the file system API.

Comment: @mhawke I expanded on my question in the main post.